# How can I generate Permutations for multiple groupings in a list in Python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I know that we can use itertools.permutations to permutate different items in a list however, what if I have a list such that few items need to be in fixed positions, few items need to be swapped with one more and few items need to be swapped with 2 more?

For example:

```
test = [1, 6, 2, 12, 5, 13, 11, 14, 15]
```

How can I use Python itertools.permutation or another method to generate all possible combinations with the following constraints?

**Update:**

```
1 and 5 have fixed positions
In position 2, I could have either 6 or 11
In position 3, I could have either 2 or 12
In position 4, I could have 2 or 12
In position 6, I could have either 13, 14, 15 and so on
```

So, my list looks like this:

```
[1, (6, 11), (2, 12), (2,12), 5, (13, 14, 15), (6, 11), (13, 14, 15), (13, 14, 15)]
```

I have included the numbers in groups which represents that numbers in the same group can be swapped with each other.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular logic why which the elements of `test` are fixed or considered to be in swapable groups? If not, you could just compute the permuations of each hardcoded group and in the end concatenate the subresults to arrive at the final list.

Comment: As above if you know the groups that can be permutated add them to their own list `[1,[2,3,4], 5, [6,7]]` etc. and loop through and permutate when you come across a list.

Comment: @Sarcoma Yes that sounds like a good idea as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from itertools import permutations, product, chain

test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
groups = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10], [11, 12, 13], [14], [15, 16]]

result = [list(chain.from_iterable(permutation)) for permutation in product(*map(permutations, groups))]

for e in result[:20]:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11, 13, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 11, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 11, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 11, 12, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 14, 16, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12, 13, 11, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12, 13, 11, 14, 16, 15]
```

**UPDATE**

Given the new constraints you can do something like this:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import combinations, permutations, product, chain

choose_one = partial(lambda r, iterable: combinations(iterable, r), 1)
groups = [[[1]], combinations([6, 11], 1), permutations([2, 12]), [[5]], combinations([13, 14, 15], 1)]

for e in product(*groups, repeat=1):
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(e)))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 6, 2, 12, 5, 13]
[1, 6, 2, 12, 5, 14]
[1, 6, 2, 12, 5, 15]
[1, 6, 12, 2, 5, 13]
[1, 6, 12, 2, 5, 14]
[1, 6, 12, 2, 5, 15]
[1, 11, 2, 12, 5, 13]
[1, 11, 2, 12, 5, 14]
[1, 11, 2, 12, 5, 15]
[1, 11, 12, 2, 5, 13]
[1, 11, 12, 2, 5, 14]
[1, 11, 12, 2, 5, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks, if I call the len method on the list above called, result, I only get a value of 288. I thought there would be more possible combinations than that? Is there a way to know the total number of combinations mathematically? :)

Comment: @NeonFlash I believe that number to be right you have two groups of 3 elements, 3 of two elements and 4 of 1 element. The permutations of a group of 3 elements is 6, of 2 elements is 2 and of one element is one. Then you have to multiply all of them `6**2 * 2**3 * 1**4 = 288`

Comment: Thanks, I actually think I didn't make my question clear. I updated it now. Could you please check? There can only be one number out of those possible numbers in that position. For example, in position 2, I can have either 6 or 11. I think it involves both permutation and combination.

Comment: @NeonFlash Updated the answer! As you guessed it involves permutation and combination.